# Locate & count all duplicates of subset of columns in table with query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and how to make the query work?

I'm trying to return {OrgID, IdentifierTypeID, IdentifierOrder, ValidFrom} for all records where those 4 columns are duplicated along with the count of duplicates.  I only want duplicates shown in the result set, that's why I tried the > 1 part.

```
select count(*) Number, OrgID, IdentifierTypeID, IdentifierOrder, ValidFrom
    from xdb.dbo.OrganizationIdentifier_IngestII
    where Number > 1
    group by OrgID, IdentifierTypeID, IdentifierOrder, ValidFrom
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a HAVING clause to test the result of an aggregate function. Also, you cannot use the column alias (Number) in that test, so you'll need to repeat the function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number, OrgID, IdentifierTypeID, IdentifierOrder, ValidFrom
    FROM xdb.dbo.OrganizationIdentifier_IngestII
    GROUP BY OrgID, IdentifierTypeID, IdentifierOrder, ValidFrom
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```